# Flutter Google Map Issue

Tags: google-maps, flutter

A very bare-bone application that has nothing but a Google Map screen, copies from Codelabs with the following:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Upon running the app crashes and I get the following stack:

=========================================

```
    *** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x00000001050730e3 +[GMSServices checkServicePreconditions] + 182
    4   Runner                              0x000000010506ff22 +[GMSServices sharedServicesSync] + 110
    5   Runner                              0x000000010505f979 -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:forPlaces:] + 156
    6   Runner                              0x000000010505ede1 -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:] + 123
    7   Runner                              0x000000010505ec05 +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:] + 104
    8   Runner <…>
Lost connection to device.
```

============================================

The plugin used is: google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.11

What is happening here?

Comment: Did you add google_api_key for Google map into  your flutter app?
if not then follow [readMe](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter).

Comment: Yes, API was added to AppDelegate.m and info.plist was edited, per instructions. Funny thing is that I have an older app, going back about a year that works fine with Google Maps, but I cannot create any new ones that work.

Answer (score 0):

Add code define API key google map on **AppDelegate.swift**

```
  GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_KEY")
```